# Azure DevOps REST: Retrieve all warning messages from build

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet package to access these REST APIs; I have this working well for a number of different scenarios already. A new requirement is to surface all the warning messages emitted during a build pipeline.

My initial call to

```c#
Timeline timeline = await BuildHttpClient.GetBuildTimelineAsync(project, buildId);
```

seemed to be what I was looking for, as calling `timeline.Records.Select(r => r.WarningCount).Sum()` returns the same number of warnings as displayed on the build summary in the web UI, and warnings are appearing in the `Issues` property of the `Records` instances. However, for a build that returned 14000+ warnings, `timeline.Records.SelectMany(r => r.Issues)` is returning only 57 in total; the API appears to only be returning the first ten or so warnings from each task the pipeline executed.

I've seen elsewhere that I could do something like

```c#
Stream s = await BuildHttpClient.GetBuildLogAsync(project, buildId, logId);
```

to get the logs individually for each task (after enumerating them with a separate call) then parse the returned stream for warning codes, but as there are quite a few tasks in this pipeline, some of them with rather verbose logging, I would prefer to avoid hammering the services more than necessary, as well as downloading large quantities of data unnecessarily.

Is there a more efficient mechanism for retrieving a collection of all warning (and, optionally, error) messages, or something I've missed in the REST docs, such as a way of getting the timeline service call to return them all?